# Create and import only last sheet data with found error "UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file."

Tags: python, dataframe, html-table, spreadsheet, export-to-excel

When I run blow code I got `error : UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file. warn("Calling close() on already closed file.")`

I cannot save my first three code and excel sheet also.

```
import openpyxl
from os import path
import pandas as pd

def load_workbook(wb_path):
    if path.exists(wb_path):
        return openpyxl.load_workbook(wb_path)
    return openpyxl.Workbook()

wb_path = './output/trail.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(wb_path)

list = [530001, 530011, 530017, 530023]

for item in list:
    url_1 = f'https://www.screener.in/company/{item}/'

    df0 = pd.read_html(url_1)
        
    data1 = df0[1]
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter(wb_path) as writer:

        data1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(item),startcol=0 ,startrow=1,index=False)
        
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: please don't call a list "list". `list` is a built-in data type in Python, which your code is overwriting. E.g.:

```
print(type(list))
<class 'type'>

list=[1,2,3]

print(type(list))
<class 'list'>
```

Your error is related to this info from the [`pd.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) documentation:

> The writer should be used as a context manager. Otherwise, call *close()* to save and close any opened file handles.

Since you are indeed using `pd.ExcelWriter` as a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) (through the `with` statement), the file will already be saved and closed, when you get to the line `writer.save()`. We don't need it.

The next problem is that `pd.ExcelWriter` is used with the default `mode`, namely `"w"` (write). In this mode you keep overwriting the same (first) sheet. This is the reason why you end up with only the data from the last `item`. To avoid this, use `mode="a"` (append). Probably also wise to specify `if_sheet_exists="replace"` (or whatever you prefer; have a look at the options). Let's also specify the engine: `engine="openpyxl"`.

Finally, your current code will open/save/close the file 4 times, namely during each loop. This is unnecessary. To avoid this, simply place the `for loop` within the `with` statement. So, putting that all together:

```
lst = [530001, 530011, 530017, 530023]
    
with pd.ExcelWriter(wb_path, mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    
    for item in lst:
        url_1 = f'https://www.screener.in/company/{item}/'
    
        df0 = pd.read_html(url_1)
            
        data1 = df0[1]
    
        data1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(item),startcol=0 ,startrow=1,index=False)
```

Result:

[image: xslx-writer]